# How to Read Data From JavaDB

Tags: java, javadb

I have tried to create a simple Java application that will read data from the JavaDB. 
The purpose is to get the first "UNAME" variable from the database and assign it to the "user" variable and print it.

```
package giris;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

/**
 *
 * @author Ibrahim
 */
public class Giris {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String user = "";

        System.out.println("hello world");
        try 
        { 
            System.out.println("connecting to database");    
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/deneme", "ASD", "asd");
            System.out.println("succesfully connected");
            PreparedStatement pr = con.prepareStatement("select UNAME from ASD.Table1");

            ResultSet rs = pr.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next())
            {

            user = rs.getString(0);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println("error");
        }
        System.out.println(user);
    }

}
```

[This is how my DB looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMUXP.png)

However, when I run the application the output is like this:

```
run:
hello world
connecting to database

error
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Maybe you should look at the exception.

Comment: Are you sure to use the username here `ASD.Table1`, I think you just need to use `select UNAME from Table1`

Comment: Changed ASD.Table1 to Table1, result is still the same, I think the problem might be with database connection, because I cannot get the "successfully connected" output. But I still do not know where I made a mistake.

Comment: Maybe you should look at the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading driver class logic is missing, please add this

```
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver").newInstance();
```

add this derbyclient-10.2.2.0.jar to classpath

hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

You used it correctly, maybe wrong DB details.

BTW, never use catch block like that, you are missing the information stored in **e**.

Use below code for more information:

```
public static void yourMethod()
{
    try
    {
        // Some code...
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        logError("Got exception during...", e);
    }
}

public static void logError(String message, Throwable e)
{
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
    e.printStackTrace(pw);

    logError(message + "\n" + sw.toString());
}

public static void logError(String message)
{
    System.err.println("[ERROR] " + message);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help, I am sure that DB details are correct, I even created another one to make sure. It seems like there is another problem.